# Python - wrong encoding, regexp

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I have a text in Polish language in which I want to filter out non-Polish letters, but the problem is that Polish specific letters disappear

```
# coding: utf-8
import re

_NOT_LETTERS = re.compile('[^a-ząćęłóńśżź]+')

text = u'dzień dobry i wszystkiego najlepszego życzę'

data = _NOT_LETTERS.sub(' ', text)

print data
```

and the result is

```
 dzie dobry i wszystkiego najlepszego ycz
```

instead of expected

```
dzień dobry i wszystkiego najlepszego życzę
```

How can I fix this ? I receive variable text from a third-party library

Comment: The pattern must use a unicode string too: `re.compile(u'[^a-ząćęłóńśżź]+')` otherwise multibyte characters are seen as separated bytes *(ie: one byte, one char)*.

Comment: Great, it works. If you want add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accented letters are not in the ascii range and need several bytes when encoded in UTF-8, for example the character:

```
U+0144  ń       LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE
```

is encoded on two bytes: `c5 84`

When you write a string without specifying that it is a string with multibyte characters, each single byte is seen as a character (the character `\xc5` and the character `\x84` but not the character `ń` (U+0144) that isn't recognized.)

In Python 2.7 you need to specify that your string is a unicode string otherwise all multibyte characters are seen as single bytes. You can test it yourself writing:

```
>>> text = u'dzień'
>>> [c for c in text]
[u'd', u'z', u'i', u'e', u'\u0144']

>>> text = 'dzień'
>>> [c for c in text]
['d', 'z', 'i', 'e', '\xc5', '\x84']
```

Characters are not found because your pattern isn't in a unicode string like your subject string. You need to write:

```
re.compile(u'[^a-ząćęłóńśżź]+')
```